# memcpy c++ - crashing

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a very simple routine (at least should be simple)

I create a large char array and I am copying data to it as I receive it moving. After about the third iteration the app crashes.

first create a large buffer

```
_buffer = new char(7931880);

...

void writeData(char* newData,size_t size)
{
  memcpy(_buffer,newData,size); //this call succeeds the first 4 times then fails bytes received
 _buffer+=size;                 //(size) is never larger than 16000
}
```

Comment: did you mean `_buffer = new char(7931880);` or should it be `_buffer = new char[7931880];`

Comment: Note, however, that `memcpy` is generally inadvisable in C++; use `std::copy` instead.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: nitpicker

Comment: @akira: Not really nitpicking ;)  `std::copy` works in general, `memcpy` only works on POD types.  Plus it doesn't require you to think about size.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth There are uses for `memcpy`, I think. In particular `memcpy` is specially blessed to be able to copy memory between types where casting pointers to `char*` and using `std::copy` may be an aliasing violation.

Comment: Once you fix `new T()` to `new T[]`, use `std::vector<T>` instead of `new T[]`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: so std::copy now knows about when to stop when you feed `char* ` into it? aside from that: this nuance is irrelevant for OP's problem, OP has problems to understand how to allocate stuff on the heap via `new`.

Comment: @akira: Yes, that's why I put it in a comment ;)

Comment: Compiler warnings are your friends. When your code causes the compiler to emit them, you should figure out why. If you don't know why the compiler is complaining, they are likely errors. That's why the warnings were put there in the first place.

Answer (score 22):

```
_buffer = new char(7931880);
```

This is a pointer to a SINGLE character. To get an array use

```
_buffer = new char[7931880];
```

And turn on compiler warnings to detect the overflow.

Comment: After trying out the code it seems that actually g++ 4.6.3 and 4.7.1 gives this overflow warning without any switch. So the "turn on" is actually "look at" for this question. But it is always a good idea to turn them on anyway.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast response -[] was what I wanted.

Comment: @user1984724: That's what the little 'accept this answer' checkbox is for. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You are dynamically allocating a single `char` with value `7931880`. Making an assumption that your buffer should be a little more than a single `char` (not much of a buffer), perhaps you were looking for `_buffer = new char[7931880];`. This would allocate 7931880 `char`s.

Comment: it's important to highlight the difference between `(` and `[`.